# Wordpress auto picking featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails

In the past when I created a news post, the featured image was automatically assigned to the post when I uploaded an image in the post.

But now, that doesn't work anymore :(
The only thing that changed was that I installed certain plugins for testing and deactivated them afterwards.

First I found out that I didn't add theme support for featured images.
Added this code in my functions.php:

```
// This theme uses post thumbnails
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

I can now see the featured images in the back-end and add it manually.
But how come it was automatically in the past?

I'm using WordPress 3.7.1–nl_NL with my custom theme and the following plugins:

- All In One SEO Pack
- Google XML Sitemaps
- Jetpack by WordPress.com
- Limit Login Attempts
- SI CAPTCHA Anti-Spam
- WP Anti Spam

Comment: WordPress does not automatically assign featured images. What Theme were/are you using, and what Plugins are active? I assume you have changed the Theme. If so, you will need to identify the previous Theme, and the code that Theme used to auto-assign featured images.

Comment: @ChipBennett, I did not change theme, I'm still using my own custom theme. I've added the active plugins to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a function for that. Use this code below in your functions.php file and it will add a featured image automatically:

```
/* Generate Featured Image Automatically */

function autoset_featured() {
          global $post;
          $already_has_thumb = has_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
              if (!$already_has_thumb)  {
              $attached_image = get_children( "post_parent=$post->ID&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&numberposts=1" );
                          if ($attached_image) {
                                foreach ($attached_image as $attachment_id => $attachment) {
                                set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $attachment_id);
                                }
                           }
                        }
      }
add_action('the_post', 'autoset_featured');
add_action('save_post', 'autoset_featured');
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'autoset_featured');
add_action('new_to_publish', 'autoset_featured');
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'autoset_featured');
add_action('future_to_publish', 'autoset_featured');
```

Answer (score 0):

> *...how come it was automatically in the past?*

—it has no answer actually. Any intertwining code can filter featured image from your post, or you could misunderstand the thing at past - anything can be - I have no idea.

The thing is that: to show the post thumbnail into anywhere, whether in home page (blog feed) or in post detail page, you need to call another function:

```
the_post_thumbnail();
```

To show featured image on home page, use the code in `index.php` (or any interlinked template), and to show into the detail page, use the code in `single.php`.